# How to subscribe several Observables in an array but one at a time?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, rxjs6

I have a list of tasks in array and I need to run them making a call to a web service.

But the thing is, they are in an array and I need to run **one at a time**, meaning: **only run the next one when this one is finished**, no matter if an error occurred or not.

I have this code here where I use **combineLatest**, but this way I only get the result when ALL them are finished.

```
let arrayOfTasks: ServerTask[] = cacheInfo.cacheData;
let observables = [];
arrayOfTasks.forEach((task: ServerTask) => {
  if (task.method === 'post') {
    let observable$: any = this.restService.sendPost(task.action, task.payload, false, task.cacheName);
    observables.push(observable$);
  }
});

const combined = combineLatest(observables);
combined.subscribe((value: any[]) => {
  console.log('ARRAY DATA RETURNED');
  console.log(value);
}, error => {
  console.error(`Error running stored tasks: ${error}`);
}, () => {
  console.log('All cache tasks executed...');
});
```

### Any thoughts?

**Edit 1:**

As suggested by @trichetriche here is the final solution:

```
concat(...observables).subscribe((result: any) => {
  console.log('RESULT: ', result);
}, error => {
  console.error(`Error running queue of tasks: ${error}`)
}, () => {
  console.log('All subscriptions executed');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `concat` for that, coupled with an array reducer :

```
obs$
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.pipe(concat(curr)), of(undefined))
  .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

You can even use the creator `concat` instead of the operator :

```
concat(...obs$)
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ni77ae?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the second option worked like a charm, but I confess that is a little bit advanced for my knowledge of RxJs yet, I really need to understand the concept of that solution. What really the *concat" does there?

Comment: Using the contact creator is there any way I know they were all executed? The reason is I need to empty the array in the end.

Comment: [In simplified words](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html), it simply concats observables, like you would concatenate an array. [Look at the source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/concat.ts#L116), if you want to know more

Comment: @franzmobile what do you mean ? You want to empty the array when you make a call ?

Comment: I want to empty the array when ALL the observables have been subscribed.

Comment: But you want to keep the ones that have been in error ?

Comment: It's alright, see my Edit 1, that way is perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @devnosaur no problem, if you feel I have helped resolving your issue, be sure to mark my answer as the accepted one !